# Send data without submit button (Javascript / jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="form1" id="form1" action="coillist" method="POST">
            <table id="dataTable" border="1">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Coil #</th><th>Width</th><th>Gauge</th>
                    </tr>   

                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" maxlength="7" size="7" name="coil_id" value="coil_11"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" size="7" name="width" value="120"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" size="5" name="gauge" value="130"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" maxlength="7" size="7" name="coil_id" value="coil_22"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" size="7" name="width" value="220"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" size="5" name="gauge" value="330"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" maxlength="7" size="7" name="coil_id" value="coil_33"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" size="7" name="width" value="320"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" size="5" name="gauge" value="330"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have a dynamic row adding table that could add row into the table. 
I am showing it in 3 rows, it could be 1 row, or 4 rows, or n rows if a use wants to add data in.

My question is: How can I send data (`coil_id`) out without click submit button?

In this example, I want to send a `coil_id` (`coil_id = ”coil_22”` in this case) to the server without using submit button.

This is also something like: detect if user enter a coil in length of 7 char or digit (Ex: `coil_22` or `2C12345`), then it will submit the `“coil_22”`   (not `coilL_11` or `coil_33`) to server without click any submit / send button.

I have used JavaScript / jQuery a while, still feel lost sometimes.

Highly appreciate your help.

Comment: search for ajax request, send it in callback function of keyup event of input

Comment: when do you wish to send those data? something have to trigger that. you can trigger submiting (non ajax) by `$('#form').submit()`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it with a `.keyup()`, just add a class to each input for example

```
<input type="text" class="coil_input" maxlength="7" size="7" name="coil_id" value="coil_11">
<input type="text" class="coil_input" maxlength="7" size="7" name="coil_id" value="coil_22">

<script>
    $('.coil_input').keydown(function() {
       if($.trim($(this).val()).length == 7){
           var now_input_value = $(this).val();
           $.post('file.php', {now_input: now_input_value}, function(){ alert('Data sent'); }).fail(function(){ alert('An error has ocurred'); });
       }
   });
</script>
```

All the inputs has to have the same class

Remember to add jQuery to your document.

Comment: it seems to be working, this is a J2EE / JSP application, so it would be file.java I guess.

Comment: I think it has to be a .js file to work I'm not sure if it will works if is saved as a .java file

Comment: it works for the first row, the table has a dynamic duplicated row if user want to add a row, the script code I put in does not get copy, I will try more with the similar idea.

Comment: yes, jquery execute that funcion at `$(document).ready()` only once but check this out is pure javascript http://jsfiddle.net/Memolition/WYLn2/

Comment: This one is working, sorry for replying late. I am going to use it. Thanks for place the demo code in jsfiddle.net, that helps a lot.

Comment: A silly question if you don't mind, how I can refer back to the row that sent and received data from server, in this example, not the 1st or 3rd row, but the 2nd row.

Comment: where do you need to use it?, cause you can make it in your `jQuery`: `var now_input_id = $(this).attr('id');` or send the id to php and return it to the `function(){alert('data sent');}` but you add `function(r){ alert('data sent row with id' + r); }` and in you php you echo the id

Comment: the code is like:var                                              inputValue = funnjsTrim(elem.value);
$.post('cglChecklist', {inputCoil: inputValue}, function(){ alert('Data sent -- ' +inputValue); }).fail(function(){ alert('An error has ocurred'); });
This is a jsp/Java app, I got the data in java, so the return data can be processed inside the function(){alert('data sent');}  ??

Comment: where are you setting the `elem` variable used on the `funnjsTrim()` function?

Comment: The part of sending data out is working, the server get the data for the id sent from js. I try to find out how I can pass a value (for example, "3456") back to the JavaScript or my client page.

Comment: Have you already tried echo(in your php) `echo $_POST['inputCoil'];` and use the jQuery response `function(r){ alert('data sent row with id' + r); }` add `function(r)` and the `r` will turn into a variable that can be used inside that function

Comment: This is Java / JSP app. it is different from php, I need to use the respond writer() to set the return data. it works out now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

here is example of jquery ajax. serialize will create generate query string that will be sent to your url.

```
var datastring = $("#yourForm").serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "your url",
    data: datastring,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) { alert('all ok');}
 });
```

Comment: I tried this one, for some reason it does not fire up, do I miss something? I am getting the idea, though, I am kine of new to ajax.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It does fire with some error after I placing the "error:" line. it seems to be my problem. I will tried this idea with other similar things.