# Not able to post PHP variable to another page

Tags: php

I have a date variable set in my page and I want to post it to another page.

Here's the PHP code in the first page:

```
<?php if(isset($date)) { echo $date; ?>

<form action="new.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="date" id="date" value="<?php echo htmlentities ($date); ?>">
</form>

<?php } ?>
```

$date is echoed when the date is set in the request so there is no issue with that.

In new.php

```
$mydate = $_GET['date'];
```

But when I dump the data in new.php all I get is NULL.

I want to do this specifically with hidden form inputs or any other solution that does not involve using sessions.

This seems so fundamental what am I doing wrong? I've checked my console and there are no errors over there.

**UPDATE**

```
<?php if(isset($date)) { echo $date; ?>

<form name="dateform" id="dateform" action="news_detail.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="date" id="date" value="<?php echo htmlentities ($date); ?>">

</form>
```

In my script:

```
document.dateform.submit();
```

Comment: `$mydate = $_GET['date'];` to `$mydate = $_POST['date'];`

Answer (score 2):

You need to make use of **`POST`** , since your **`<form>`** tag has the action method **`POST`**

```
$mydate = $_POST['date'];
```

### Simple Illustration

```
<?php
@extract($_POST);
if(isset($submit)) {
    echo $_POST['date'];
}
 ?>

    <form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="date" id="date" value="23-4-2025">
        <input type='submit' name='submit'>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$_GET` is for GET data.

`$_POST` is for POST data.

`$_COOKIE` is for COOKIE data.

`$_REQUEST` is for ^ALL^ the data.

Answer (score 0):

you are passing varible using POST method from first page and second page you are retriving it ussing $_POST[]...

chage second page like this

```
 $mydata=$_POST['data'] will work
```

and use submit button to send data to the **new.php**

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send"/>
```

Comment: I had tried that before and I did again now. Still doesn't work :/

Comment: @Paulie how you are submitting data? please show us code and if you are not using any submit button then use it as i explained in my answer

Answer (score 0):

since ur using post method.correct fetching of the data as the same method i.e. post.and if u r not sure which method u r using u can use $_REQUEST as well.but the later has some security issues.

```
<?php if(isset($date)) { echo $date; ?>
<form action="new.php" name="myform" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="date" id="date" value="<?php echo htmlentities ($date); ?>">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

than in new.php use the following code to fetch the data

```
$mydate = $_POST['date'];
```

with javascript(no need to use submit button):
[Send data without submit button (Javascript / jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242234/send-data-without-submit-button-javascript-jquery)

Comment: I had tried that before and I did again now. Still doesn't work :/

Comment: @Paulie thats because u r not using any submit button in your form. :)

Comment: is that really required? cause most tutorials don't use a submit button in the form since it's a hidden input anyway

Comment: ya submit is necessary.hidden input means that the input will not shown to the user.but without creating a submit button u cant send data(query string) to the server if ur not using javascript or ajax.if u have doubt let me know.

Comment: okay that works but I don't want the button to pop up. How can I do it via javascript/ajax then?

Comment: @Paulie i edited my code and that is working perfectly when i checked,so u can use that :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734901/how-to-submit-a-form-on-page-load-without-clicking-submit-button

Comment: yes it does work perfectly :)  but I don't want the button to pop up or have to be clicked.

Comment: @paulie go through the link i shared,u will get your answer :)   http://www.hotscripts.com/forums/php/5387-post-without-submit-button.html

Comment: @paulie did u find ur solution? u need to include <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
//submit form
document.order.submit();
</script>

Comment: @Paulie whats the problem you are facing now.?

Comment: this works perfectly with the button in place but not with the javascript when I remove the button.

Comment: i edited my code .have a look and give name attribute to ur form and use the javascript code i have written.

Comment: @paulie- ya u r right.i edited my post and shared a link that may be the possible copy of wat u r looking for.have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Must have some value in $date to enter into your form section

page1.php

```
$date ="some date";

<?php if(isset($date)) { echo $date; ?>

    <form action="new.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="date" id="date" value="<?php echo htmlentities ($date); ?>">
    </form>

    <?php } ?>
```

Now new.php, On page1.php submit

```
echo $mydate = $_POST['date'];
```